# How do I get my original MAC address? 

Tags: windows-7, networking, mac-address

I am using Windows 7 Home Basic. My laptop's MAC address was changed by a hardware support person to facilitate my Internet connection.

How can I get my original MAC address.

Answer (score 2):

[Technitium MAC Address Changer](http://www.technitium.com/tmac/index.html) can show you the original MAC address.

Comment: And it's freeware! Good link!